# Why does my CMD prompt do nothing when I use the "python manage.py runserver" command after activating the virtual environment for my Django project

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Not using a virtual environment,on my command prompt, "python manage.py command" works but when I activate the virtual environment and use "python manage.py command" it just goes to the next line without doing anything

Comment: Only activating the environment won't work you need to go to the project directory. For example, you created a project named stocks. So you used the command `django-admin startproject stocks`. Now you need to run the `python manage.py runserver` command inside the project. By doing `cd stocks` you enter in the project folder. And then run the server .

Comment: Yes sir/ma, I was in the directory when I tried to run the server.it just goes to the next line without doing anything

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the virtual environment again using this command :
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper-win

then make a new virtual env using:
mkvirtualenv django_env_name

then install your django in this env using : pip install django
(if env is not activated , then run this command : workon django_env_name)

Then simply go to project dir and run command : python manage.py runserver

Comment: I have Django installed on my computer, do I also have to install it in the virtual environment?

Comment: It's not compulsory to install in virtual environment, but it is a good practice to make a virtual environment because if you are working on different projects and they are in different django versions then you can maintain virtual environments for them with different versions installed in it.